# Hidding system clock from OS X menu bar with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to hide the system clock from the menu bar, through an App, at will?

I mean the same thing that can be done by un-ckecking the "Preferences / Date & Time / Clock / Show date and time in menu bar" option.

Comment: Why ? Why do you need such a thing ? And what do you know about programming ? AS ? C++ ? Obj-c?

Comment: I'm working on my first OS X app.  This would be a feature of it, not something to trick the user.  I'm a software engineer with quite a bit of experience with other technologies.

Comment: And which language do you use to create your application ?

Comment: Then did you search on google how to change preferences using Obj-C?

Comment: I searched, but couldn't find anything.  I didn't think of using the language for the query.  Thanks for nudging me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this. 
If you have a need for it, file a bug or use a DTS incident. 
If you want a kiosk mode you can hide the menu bar or create a full screen window.